# vue and webpack doesn't do lazy loading in components?

Tags: vue.js, webpack

The lazy component in vue/webpack seem to be wrong or I miss confuse about the terms.

To do lazy loading of component I use the keyword `import` and webpack should split this component to sepeate bundle, and when I need to load this component webpack should take care of it and load the component.

but in fact, webpack does make sperate file, but it loaded anyway when the application is running. which is unexpected.

[image]

For example I just  create a simple vue application (using the cli) and browse to `localhost:8080/` and the about page should be loaded (by default) using the `import` keyword.

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'About',
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '../views/About.vue')
  }
]
```

So This is by design? I load every time the file I do not need right now (the page about). and if I have 200 pages, when I'll fetch 200 files I dont need. how that ends up? that did I save here by using the `import` key?

In [vuetify](https://www.vuetifyjs.com/) for example they uses `import` key, but the files are loaded anyway and not by demand.

Comment: It's possible, you just have to set it up. https://blog.logrocket.com/lazy-loading-in-vue-js/

Comment: you can see Im using import keyword in about route.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also avoid component prefetch using one of the webpack "magic" comments (https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#prefetchingpreloading-modules), eg.

```
components: {
  MyComponent: () => import(/* webpackPrefetch: false */ './MyComponent.vue')
}
```

Feel free to read more about this Vue optimization below:

https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/lazy-loading-individual-vue-components-and-prefetching/

Comment: webpackPrefetch: false doesn't work -> false is supposed to be the default setting, but when I try it I get a warning: "webpackPrefetch expected true or a number, but received: false. (magic comment)"

Answer (score 2):

If you're referring to the default app template from Vue CLI, then you're actually observing the [prefetch](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#prefetch) of the About page,  intended to reduce load times for pages the user will likely visit.

If you want to avoid this performance optimization, use this Vue config:

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.plugins.delete('prefetch')
    config.plugins.delete('preload')
  }
}
```

---

For troubleshooting reference, Chrome's Network panel includes an [*Initiator* column](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference#initiators-dependencies), which provides a clickable link to the source file that triggered the network call. In this case of the `about.js`, the source file looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

try using [vue-lazyload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-lazyload) maybe it can help and for `<script>` tags you  can try `async` `defer` it helps in website speed optimizations